# How to log actual value without introducing a variable in AppleScript

Tags: applescript

This code

```
set ver to version of application "Finder"
log ver
```

results in

```
(*10.12.1*)
```

But this code

```
log version of application "Finder"
```

spits

```
(*version*)
```

Is there a way to log the actual value without introducing a variable? I.e. what's the magic keyword for evaluation?

Comment: `log` can be remarkably unhelpful, unfortunately; see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13653358/how-to-log-objects-to-a-console-with-applescript/21341372#21341372) of mine - which does require some setup, however.

Comment: `version of application "Finder"` `log result` - or `log (get version of application "Finder")`

Comment: try --> log (the version of application "Finder")